# Dynamic programming in JavaScript, find valid sentences in a string with no spaces

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a string with no spaces or puncation, S, of n uppercase letters, describe an efficient way of breaking it into a sequence of valid English words. You may assume that you have a function, valid(s), which can take a character string, s, and return true if and only if s is a valid English word. 
Ex input: ABORTTHEPLANMEETATTHEDARKCABIN

My attempt results in a memory overflow error. 

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
var test = 'ABORTTHEPLANMEETATTHEDARKCABIN';
var words = {
    ABORT: true,
    THE: true,
    PLAN: true,
    MEET: true,
    AT: true,
    DARK: true,
    CABIN: true
};

var valid = function(word) {
    if (words[word]) return true;
    return false;
};

var decodeMessage = function(S) {
    if (S.length === 0) return '';
    if (S.length === 1) return S[0];

    var prev_combos = [
        [S[0]]
    ];

    var new_combos, temp;
    for (var j = 1; j < S.length; j++) {
        new_combos = [];
        for (var k = 0; k < prev_combos.length; k++) {
            temp = prev_combos[k].slice();
            temp[temp.length - 1] += S[j];
            new_combos.push(temp);
            prev_combos[k].push(S[j]);
            new_combos.push(prev_combos[k]);
        }
        prev_combos = new_combos;
    }

    var all_words_valid, valid_combos = [];
    for (var l = 0; l < new_combos.length; l++) {
        all_words_valid = true;
        for (var m = 0; m < new_combos[l].length; m++) {
            console.log(new_combos[l][m]);
            if (!valid(new_combos[l][m])) {
                all_words_valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (all_words_valid) {
            valid_combos.push(new_combos[l].join(' '));
        }
    }

    return valid_combos;
};

console.log(decodeMessage(test));
```

Comment: Your 'valid' function returns either undefined or false. There is missing 'true'.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix the memory overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer online, if only I saw it sooner!
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/

Comment: That isn't actually what you asked / stated above in your question. Whether it was what you meant to be asking is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. Only lightly tested but should suffice. It does assume (as does the question I believe ?) that no two words are subsets of one another. Eg. THE, THEATRE etc. Modifying the code to do that would be reasonably straightforward but very different in terms of performance to this solution.

```
'use strict';

var words = {
    ABORT: true,
    THE: true,
    PLAN: true,
    MEET: true,
    AT: true,
    DARK: true,
    CABIN: true
},

validWord = function(word) {
    return !!words[word];
},

decrypt = function(encrypted) {
    var result = encrypted.split('').reduce(function (prev, cur) {
        var value = (prev.temp) ? prev.temp + cur : cur,
          found = validWord(value);
        if (found) {
            prev.words.push(value);
            prev.temp = '';
        } else {
            prev.temp = prev.temp + cur;
        }
        return prev;
    }, { words: [], temp: ''});
    return result.words.join(' ');
},

// test a few scenarios
encrypted = ['', 'Z', 'ABORT', 'ABORTTHEPLANMEETATTHEDARKCABIN'];

encrypted.map(decrypt);

// ["", "", "ABORT", "ABORT THE PLAN MEET AT THE DARK CABIN"]
```

The basic idea is to split the encrypted sentence (string) into an array, traverse that array using the built-in array.reduce() function using a collecting param object, then join the resulting array of words back into the decrypted sentence (string) again for presentation.

Hope it helps. I personally prefer using higher order functions to lower level for loops, and believe in this situation it is reasonably performant as we only traverse the array of chars once.

Comment: Where does the dynamic programming come into play? If there cant be subsets does that mean there will be only one possible valid sentence? Do you think my solution is correct if I assume there can be subsets?

Comment: @DanielKobe - you could have different sentences, but the solution eagerly picks a word as valid as soon as a match is found ie.  if you had words = ["THE", "THEATRE"], and a sentence "MY THEATRE", the above would currently see "THE" as the valid word to extract because it is a subset of THEATRE.  The program could be altered to keep checking for matches forwards (using a lookahead approach), and then pick the longest matching word. Your question did not specify this as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line may be causing the memory overflow error: `new_combos.push(prev_combos[k]);`